# Linux command to move a directory

Tags: linux, command-line, mv

My old and new directory have same folders and files inside.

I try:

```
mv -if old/* new/*
```

and get error

> mv: cannot move `./xxxxxx' to a subdirectory of itself

How can I move it?

Comment: This is a perfectly good question that belongs on StackOverflow.  Granted, it is a naive mistake - but that's what SO is for; it helps people overcome naivety by allowing them to ask questions and learn from answers.  See SO Blog and Podcast #53 (Joel says no question is too simple for Stack Overflow...).

Comment: But it's not a programming question. Doesn't it belong on ServerFault?

Comment: ServerFault is still in private beta!

Comment: It is about how to program shell - it is OK on SO.

Comment: If 'mv' is programming shell, I'll eat my hat (or I would if I had one).

Comment: ahh. thanks for all. I should read the rules before posting.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: I searched for 'mv' and got 5 pages of answers at 50 answers per page.  This one is not out of order.

Comment: If you don't like the question, vote it down and move on.

Comment: See also: [How do I rename a directory via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56326/how-do-i-rename-a-directory-via-the-command-line)

Comment: 'mv -if' is silly, as man mv states: if you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes effect. It should be just 'mv -i'.

Answer (score 32):

You should use `mv -if old/* new/` without the trailing `*`.

This is because it unrolled to

```
mv -if old/foo old/bar old/baz new/foo new/bar new/baz
```

i.e. move everything into new/baz

This is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

```
reef@localhost:/tmp/experiment$ ls a
11  22  33
reef@localhost:/tmp/experiment$ ls b
22  33
reef@localhost:/tmp/experiment$ ls
a  b
reef@localhost:/tmp/experiment$ mv a/* b
reef@localhost:/tmp/experiment$ ls a
reef@localhost:/tmp/experiment$ ls b
11  22  33
```

It works. What are You trying to achieve? Could You please write a short example of what the input data should look like and what the output data should look like? The truth is I have no idea what You are trying to do :) Help me help You.

Answer (score 4):

note that mv a/* b/ don't move files .* (file name start with '.') in a/ to b/

ex:

```
$ mkdir -p a/d b && touch a/f a/.f a/d/.f
$ mv a/* b/
$ ls -a a/
.  ..  .f
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying from an ext2/3/4 file system to a FAT32 file system, and a filename has an invalid character for FAT32 naming conventions, you get this terribly annoying and incorrect as hell error message.  How do I know? I wrestled with this bug - yes, it's a KERNEL BUG - for 6 hours before it dawned on me.  I thought it was a shell interpreter error, I thought it was an "mv" error - I tried multiple different shells, everything.  Try this experiment: on an ext file system, "touch 'a:b'" them "mv" it to a FAT32 file system.  Try it, you'll enjoy (hate) the results.  The same is true for '<' and '>' (\074 and \076).

Thanks for "man mv" - that's a real big help, don't quit your day job.

Answer (score 1):

Might be you got the answer but above answer is not working for me.... and finally lots of researching I got the answer.  (Issue is due to files-ownership)
and just put sudo before the command and its working.... :) Same thing for cp and mv command.

```
sudo mv -if old/* new/
```